# Can I declare a decorator class that extends its own type parameter?

Tags: scala

I'd like to do something like this:

```
case class D[X <: A](arg1 : X, arg2: Int) extends X {
}
```

D is kind of a decorator class for arg1, and I'd like to apply it to several different kinds of things that are subclasses of A.

However I get this error:

> scala> case class D[X <: A](arg1 : X, arg2: Int) extends X { override val name = "D"; }
>   :6: error: class type required but X found

If not, is there a more scalaish way to do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class that you extend has to be known at compile time and a type parameter is generally not. Therefore, it's not possible to do this.

However, if you're trying to extend `X` to benefit from the implementations of methods defined in an interface trait `A`, then you can mix-in `X` when instantiating the class.

```
new D with X
```

If you'd like to preserve the 'case class' features of `D`, then using `D` as a proxy which forwards calls to methods defined in `A` to the parameter `arg1` of type `X` is one solution.

```
trait A {
  def foo
}
case class D[X <: A](arg1: X) extends A {
  def forw = arg1
  def foo = forw.foo
}
```

Comment: Aha, that makes sense. A trait probably makes better sense for what I'm doing anyway. Thank you!